# Bounce in Ignition/DART

Tags: physics, gazebo-ignition

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

What is the appropriate way to set bounce in ignition?

I've successfully set bounce in gazebo by setting the `restitution_coefficient`, `threshold` and `max_vel` parameters.

[image: image description]

But these same parameters don't seem to work in ignition/DART

[image: image description]

Is bouncing not supported in ignition, or is there some additional setting that is required?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/25539/bounce-in-ignition/dart/) by [athackston](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/28658/athackston/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 17 on 2020-07-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Unfortunately, this is not yet supported in ignition. I have created an issue for it in https://github.com/ignitionrobotics/ign-physics/issues/84

---

Originally posted by [azeey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6889/azeey/) with karma: 704 on 2020-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [athackston](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/28658/athackston/) on 2020-07-18**:
Thanks! Just wanted to make sure I wasn’t missing something obvious

**Comment by [azeey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6889/azeey/) on 2021-02-02**:
This has now been fixed in Ignition Citadel. https://github.com/ignitionrobotics/ign-physics/pull/139